# magento login page, registration forms in lightbox on CMS home page in magento 1.6.1

Tags: magento

This is the second time posting this question , my client want to display login form , registration form , welcome discount in light box on CMS home page as like this website http://www.myntra.com/ ,

I tried to use lytebox module for lighbox by pasting below code in CMS home page

`<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    $lb.launch({
        url: 'test.html',     // the url to the page you want to load, or image.jpg
        options: 'width:800 height:600', // optional
        title: 'My Title', // optional
    })
]]></script>`

every thing is ok , but this lytebox script is accepting only html page instead of php or phtml files.Is there any other way to display login form in lightbox please suggest me step by step because i'm new to programming feild...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

add this code to cms/homepage

```
{{block type="core/template" template="quicklogin/quicklogin.phtml"}}
```

and this line is as first line of quicklogin/quicklogin.phtml file

```
<?php if(!$this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()): ?>
```

and complete this if condetion at last of above file

Comment: Hello naresh , very thing is ok , but missing close button for popup window ,any help

Comment: Any body please help me how can i close pop window if i use above mention method in homepage.